# Read acl white listed IP from a file on Haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I was trying to load the whitelist IP to Haproxy acl from file

I was able to whitelist ip via adding inline to haproxy config file  and its works well

I was wondering is there any way that i can specify the ip address to a file and read it from haproxy configuration

Here is my Haproxy conf

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        contimeout 5000
        clitimeout 50000
        srvtimeout 50000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    mode http
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
    acl whitelist src 192.168.12.32 192.168.0.1
    acl all src 0.0.0.0

    acl demo hdr_end(host)  -i 192.168.20.26
    use_backend demo if demo whitelist

backend demo
    balance leastconn
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    cookie JSESSIONID prefix
    server locahost localhost:8080 cookie A check
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

we specify the whitelist ip source with "-f " flag inside haproxy.conf file.

Create whitelist.lst inside /etc/haproxy/ and list out all the whitelisted ip with subnet mask  for eg:- 192.168.1.1/32 192.168.2.1/32 192.168.0.1/24 etc..

Here is my haproxy conf file which load the whitelist ip from file.

```
frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    mode http
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
    acl whitelist src -f /etc/haproxy/whitelist.lst
    acl all src 0.0.0.0

    acl demo hdr_end(host)  -i 192.168.20.26
    use_backend demo if demo whitelist

backend demo
    balance leastconn
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    cookie JSESSIONID prefix
    server locahost localhost:8080 cookie A check
```

Comment: Can you explain in a little detail what `acl demo hdr_end(host)  -i 192.168.20.26` does exactly? I'm trying to use this and things aren't working correctly. I'm thinking it's because I don't know how I should adapt this line to my particular situation.

Comment: The ACL's "demo" check which host name was requested by using hdr(host). If it matches 192.168.20.26, the acl "test_host" is set to true.  here is more simple example with hostname .  acl test_host hdr(host) -i test.example.com.

Answer (score 1):

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        contimeout 5000
        clitimeout 50000
        srvtimeout 50000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    mode http
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http

    default_backend demo

    acl white_list src -f /etc/haproxy/whitelist.lst
    tcp-request content accept if white_list
    tcp-request content reject

backend demo
    balance leastconn
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    cookie JSESSIONID prefix
    server locahost localhost:8080 cookie A check
```

Comment: Please provide some context to your answer so that others can easily understand your approach.