# haproxy ACL with dynamic pattern

Tags: haproxy

I want to use an HAProxy ACL to compare `src` (the client IP address) to a **dynamic** pattern that depends on other variables in the request - is this possible in HAProxy?

---

I am using HAProxy to route to different FIX sessions depending on the SenderCompID and client IP address. For a particular SenderCompID, I want to allow specific IP addresses and/or CIDRs. I can extract the SenderCompID to a variable, and I can query a map of SenderCompIDs to IP addresses / CIDRs, but I can't create an ACL that will tell me if the client IP is in those.

```
tcp-request content set-var(txn.accepted_ips) var(txn.sendercompid),map_str(/sender_ips.map)

# this fails
acl ip_match src -n -m ip %[var(txn.accepted_ips)]
# also fails
acl ip_match src -n -m ip var(txn.accepted_ips)
# An example of what `txn.accepted_ips` would expand to in some cases, which works when hardcoded
acl ip_match src 192.168.0.2 10.0.0.0/8

tcp-request content reject unless ip_match
```

Both options give something like

> error detected while parsing ACL 'ip_match' : '%[var(txn.accepted_ips)]' is not a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address.

I don't understand when I can expand variables in HAProxy. All of the ACL [examples](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/configuration/acls/syntax/) [I've](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/configuration/acls/acl-examples/) [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495694/read-acl-white-listed-ip-from-a-file-on-haproxy) [about](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/introduction-to-haproxy-acls#using-acls-to-block-requests) "fetch" some sort of sample from the request (`src` for the client IP in my case) and then compare to some static pattern, either via file or hardcoded in the configuration. Is it possible to compare to a dynamic pattern, or will HAProxy only expand variables in certain places?

Answer (score 1):

`value` seems static to me, but you can use converters on fetched data in ACL like this:

```
        acl test_ip src,strcmp(txn.clientip) eq 0
        http-request set-var(txn.clientip) req.hdr(clientip)
        http-request deny if test_ip
```

this is just Proof of Concept. When i send request to this localhost haproxy with HTTP header `clientip` with value `127.0.0.1` then it will block me, anything else and it will let me through.

Check [docs](https://docs.haproxy.org/2.6/configuration.html#7.3.1) for `converters`. You can chain/pipe them like this `src,strcmp(txn.clientip),add(1) eq 1`. Maybe you will find a way to make it work for you.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I have looked through every converter and I didn't see any that would expand a CIDR or compare an IP address against CIDRs.